# Celery beat_schedule works only after removing previous celerybeat-schedule files

Tags: celery

Celery beat_scheduler only works after removing below three files that are created by previous another beat_schedule task

```
rm celerybeat-schedule.bak
rm celerybeat-schedule.dat
rm celerybeat-schedule.dir
```

How could I run beat_scheduler without manual removal of such files generated previously?

Would it be related to authority?

FYI, I am running Celery through Python

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether you edit the celerybeat-schedule db manually.
In my case, I insert some data to db, worked fine in macos 10.15, but failed in ubuntu. error with `_pickle.UnpicklingError: pickle data was truncated`
So, after I insert my data to another db, such as celerybeat-schedule-{suffix}, I don't need remove this file manually anymore.